# Convert any timezone date in system timezone in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5.1

I am facing problem while converting given date into system time zone in iOS.

Source date: 2013-03-18 03:54:18 // its in AM format
Destination date should be : 2013-03-18 03:30:15 //its in PM format.

How can I get this??

I have tried below code but getting wrong data and difference too.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"Post date::%@",postDate);
NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:postDate];
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *local = [fmt stringFromDate:utc];
NSLog(@" local %@", local);

NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSString *currentDateString = [fmt stringFromDate:date1];
NSDate *currentDate = [fmt dateFromString:currentDateString];
NSUInteger flags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:utc toDate:currentDate options:0];
NSLog(@"difference::%d",[difference day]);
NSLog(@"difference::%d",[difference hour]);
NSLog(@"difference::%d",[difference minute]);
```

**EDIT:** Outputs

```
Post date::2013-03-18 03:20:09 
local 2013-03-18 03:20:09 
difference::0 
difference::13 
difference::2
```

Comment: Post date::2013-03-18 03:20:09

local 2013-03-18 03:20:09

difference::0

difference::13

difference::2

Comment: show your source date as NSDate object not as string

Comment: Post date::2013-03-17 22:24:18 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *openingHour = @"15:05:35 ";
 NSDateFormatter *workingHoursFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
        NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
        [workingHoursFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
        [workingHoursFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        NSDate *openingTime = [workingHoursFormatter dateFromString:openingHour];
```

Can you try the above code it works for me , alter the date format to your need

Comment: What is openingHour represent?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code from...

```
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

as like this

```
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

This will works for you...

Comment: After doing above changes I'm getting below results. Post date::2013-03-18 03:54:18 and local 2013-03-18 03:54:18 which is wrong.... I want that date & time in my system time zone.... but it showing wrong after this.....