# How to convert GMT to EST in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Date & time which has a format "yyyyMMddHHmmss". I am unable to convert this Time into EST time zone.I follows some tutorial but i didn't get proper result.If there is any API for this conversion please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert any timezone date in system timezone in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475348/convert-any-timezone-date-in-system-timezone-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the following way:

1) First, create an NSDateFormatter to get the NSDate

```
NSDateFormatter *serverFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[serverFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[serverFormatter setDateFormat:@"'at 'HH:mm' of 'dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

2) Convert the string (consider it is defined as theString) to a NSDate:

```
NSDate *theDate = [serverFormatter dateFromString:theString];
```

3) Create an NSDateFormatter to convert theDate to the user:

```
NSDateFormatter *userFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[userFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy"];
[userFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
```

3) Get the string from the userFormatter:

```
 NSString *dateConverted = [userFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

hope this helps you !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *startTime = @"20140508063630";
    NSDateFormatter *workingHoursFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
    [workingHoursFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [workingHoursFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSDate *openingTime = [workingHoursFormatter dateFromString:startTime];
```

Try that. Works here.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
[inputDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputDateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
[inputDateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];

NSString *outputDate = [outputDateFormat stringFromDate:[inputDateFormat dateFromString:@"20140508063630"]];
NSLog(@"%@",outputDate);
```